# How to set onfocus on dynamically created textboxes?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am having the below scenario,
 One static text box and button to add more dynamic textboxes. when the user enter keyword,i am displaying the suggestions [jquery autocomplete]. For static textbox the autocomplate function is in document.ready and for the dynamic text boxes its in "onkeypress" .

In the dynamic textboxes the autosuggestion is working fine , but the issue is with the focus. The focus is not moving to suggestion dropdown.

i tried below

```
 function getLocationList(id)
    {

      //  $('.autocomplete').css('background','none repeat scroll 0 0 #B9E5FB');

       $('.autocomplete').autocomplete({ autoFocus: true });//not working

    // Ajax Auto suggestion box.. stuff
      var optionsLocation, b;
      jQuery(function() {
      optionsLocation = { serviceUrl: '/App_Handlers/xxx.ashx',
      minChars: 2,
      delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
      deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
      noCache: false,
      width: 300
      };
      b = $("#" +id).autocomplete(optionsLocation);
      });


    }
```

also tried the below but not working

```
    $('.autocomplete').focus();
            $('.jobCenterArea').blur();
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

use $.live() like

```
  $('.autocomplete').live('focus', function(){
       // callback code here
  });
```

Comment: If hes using the current version of jquery `on` is prefererred: `$(some_element_always_in_the_dom).on('focus', '.autocomplete', function() {});`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a semi-related question regarding delegated events: [Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)

Considering `live` is now deprecated, I suggest using `on`:

```
$(document).on('focus', '.autocomplete', function(e) {
  //insert your code here for the event
});
```

Note that `document` isn't the only thing you can bind to in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed by giving the below code right after adding the dynamic textbox to html document

```
$('.autocomplete').autocomplete({ autoFocus: true });//not working

// Ajax Auto suggestion box.. stuff
  var optionsLocation, b;
  jQuery(function() {
  optionsLocation = { serviceUrl: '/App_Handlers/xxx.ashx',
  minChars: 2,
  delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
  deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
  noCache: false,
  width: 300
  };
  b = $("#" +id).autocomplete(optionsLocation);
  });
```

Thanks everybody for the i/p's